# Angular indeterminate checkbox feature not working

Tags: javascript, angular

**abc.component.html:**

```
<input class='alignedItem' type="checkbox" value="0" name={{cardProgram.id}}
[indeterminate] ="cardProgram.indeterminate"  [checked] = "cardProgram.selected" [(ngModel)]='cardProgram.selected' [disabled]='(cardProgram.appId && !hasOtherAppsAssigned(cardProgram)) && (cardProgram.appId != getAppId())'
(click)='toggleCardProgram(cardProgram,cardProgram.selected)' />

<label class='fa col-1 showMore expand-indicator' [ngClass]="{'fa-plus': !rowIsExpanded(index), 
'fa-minus': rowIsExpanded(index)}"
for='{{cardProgram.id}}'></label> 

<input #hiddenAnimationInput class='h-0' type="checkbox" id='{{cardProgram.id}}'
(change)='rowClicked(index)' />
<!-- Hidden unless toggled -->

<div class='positionUp25'>
   <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let agentItem of cardProgram.agents">
         <span class='col-12'>
         <label class='offset-1TMP col-5'>
         {{cardProgram.sys}}/{{cardProgram.prin}}/{{agentItem.agent}}
         </label>
         <label *ngIf=agentItem.application class='col-6' [ngClass]="{'text-disabled': agentItem.application && agentApp(agentItem) != getAppId()}">
         {{agentItem.application.subAppName}}
         </label>
         <label *ngIf=!agentItem.application class='col-6'>
         </label>
         <input class='alignedItem ml-3' type="checkbox" name='{{cardProgram.sys}}{{cardProgram.prin}}{{agentItem.agent}}'
         #{{cardProgram.sys}}{{cardProgram.prin}}{{agentItem.agent}}='ngModel'
         [(ngModel)]='agentItem.selected' (click)='toggleAgent(agentItem, cardProgram)'
         [disabled]='agentItem.application && agentApp(agentItem) != getAppId()' />
         </span>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

**cardPrograms.d.ts:**

```
interface CardProgram {
    .......
    indeterminate:boolean;
    checked:boolean;
    ......

}
```

**indeterminate.directive.ts**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef,Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[indeterminate]' })
export class IndeterminateDirective {
   @Input() 
   set indeterminate(value)
   {
     this.elem.nativeElement.indeterminate=value;
   }
    constructor(private elem: ElementRef) {
    }
}
```

**abc.component.ts:**

```
private toggleAgent(agent: Agent, cardProgram: CardProgram) {
    debugger;
    this.dirty = true;

    console.log("selected" + agent.selected)
    this.updateChangeValToObj(agent, cardProgram)
    //agent.selected = !agent.selected;

    if (agent.selected) {
      agent.application = this.currentApplication();
    } else {
      agent.application = null;
      // if we deselected, also unassign the app at the program level so it will reflect as 'Multiple Apps' state 
      cardProgram.application = null;
    }
   // this.togglecheckbox(cardProgram)
   var x = 0;
   cardProgram.agents.forEach(agent => {

      if (agent.selected == true) {
        ++x;
        console.log("inside agent.selected");
      }
    })

    var length = cardProgram.agents.length;

    if (x == 0) {
      console.log("x is 0");
      cardProgram.selected = false;
      cardProgram.indeterminate =false;
    }
    else if (x == length) {
      cardProgram.selected = true;
      cardProgram.indeterminate =false;
      }
    else if (x > 0 && x < length) {

      cardProgram.selected = false;
      cardProgram.indeterminate =true;

    }  
    else{
      cardProgram.indeterminate =false;
      cardProgram.selected = false;
    }

  }
```

When I select all the child check-boxes(agents), the parent should be checked and this works fine.
  When all the agents are unchecked, and then I check one of the agents the indeterminate checkbox comes up which is fine.
  **Problem scenario:** The problem comes when I check the parent checkbox which checks all the agents which is fine  but when I uncheck one of the agents, that time indeterminate option should show which is not happening. It shows unchecked for parent.

In the `abc.component.ts`, I see the control goes into `else if (x > 0 && x < length)` and sets the `cardProgram.indeterminate =true;` but the indeterminate is not shown in the UI for the above mentioned problem scenario most of the times but strangely works sometimes.

edit: Ok i have come to know exactly how to recreate the issue: lets say there are three child check boxes (agents) and all are unchecked which makes the parent unchecked. Now when I check one of child (shows indeterminate) and then check the parent checkbox(checks all the agents) and uncheck one the child then indeterminate should come up which it does not

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54075014/set-indeterminate-on-angular-checkbox/54077741#54077741

Answer (score 0):

I have done something like this before, except it was done using a mat-table and mat-checkbox. But the core implementation remains the same.

I believe the requirement is to display a table or a list with checkboxes to select each row and a master checkbox to check/uncheck all of them, and also to display an indeterminate state when some of the rows are checked.

Something like this could be done using `<mat-checkbox>` which provides the same functionality as native `<input type="checkbox">`.

**TS file**

```
intialSelection: number[] = [];
allowMultiSelect = true;
selection = new SelectionModel<number>(this.allowMultiSelect, this.intialSelection);

// checks whether the number of selected elements is equal to the total number of elements in the list
isAllSelected() {
  const numSelected = this.selection.selected.length;
  const numRows = this.sourceData.length;
  return numSelected == numRows;
}

// selects all rows if they are not selected; otherwise clears the selection
masterToggle(){
  this.isAllSelected() ?
    this.selection.clear() :
    this.sourceData.forEach(row => this.selection.select(row.Id));
}
```

**HTML File**

```
<!-- The master checkbox -->
<mat-checkbox (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null" [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()" 
    [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()">

<!-- Checkbox corresponding to individual rows -->
<mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(id) : null"
    [checked]="selection.isSelected(id)">
```

**Reference**

- https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/overview

Answer (score 0):

<input [indeterminate]="true" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"/>

Comment: Hi. plz edit your answer and use Markdown features to make the answer look better. also plz explain why do you think this is the right answer, we can not get anything from the answer.