# How to make a check box of three states

Tags: angular, checkbox

I want to make a filter using a checkbox with three states (one for online users / another for offline and the third for all) for now I have successfully made a checkbox for filtering on an off elements but I want to use checkbox inseated of my normal checkbox.

```
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef fxHide fxShow.gt-sm>Etat d'inst
                        <mat-checkbox [checked]="isSelected" (change)="onCheckboxChangeFn($event)" class="check_box_header"></mat-checkbox>
                    </mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" fxHide fxShow.gt-sm>
```

Comment: a mat-checkbox has already as property indeterminate, just [indeterminate]="isIndeterminated". If is a normal checkbox, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54075014/set-indeterminate-on-angular-checkbox/54077741#54077741

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```
<mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="checked" [(indeterminate)]="indeterminate">
       CheckBox
</mat-checkbox>
```

Add `indeterminate = true` for  third state
.Reference: https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/examples

Comment: And how I can detect if user select the first / second or third

Comment: checked will false and true for first two state and indeterminate  will be true for third state

Comment: I found that when I clicked on my checkbox for the first time I can't select indeterminate option anymore ( I want to switch between those 3 options not checked then checked then indeterminate