# Accessing MatCheckbox from AbstractControl

Tags: angular, checkbox, angular-abstract-control

I have a `MatCheckbox` in a `FormGroup` that I want to be able to read the `indeterminate` value of. But the `FormGroup` only gives me `AbstractControl`s, which do not seem be castable to, nor contain any reference to, the underlying control that I have been able to find.

How can I read the `indeterminate` value of the underlying `MatCheckbox`?

Edit: There are two .ts files that interact with my form: the first is the controller (I think that's the right term?) for the form, that has access to variables on the form, and has functions that can be called from the html. The second is a service that appears to act as a go-between between the form and other services/components. The functions in this one are also reachable from the form, but it does not appear to be able to touch the form itself; it is in this service that I am handed the group of `AbstractControl`, but I haven't quite been able to figure out how (this wasn't originally written by me). This service is where I need to be able to determine whether or not `indeterminate` is set on the `MatCheckbox` referenced by the `AbstractControl`.

Comment: To make it more clear, please provide an example of your code where the `FormGroup` is handled and the parts of the component and the template related with the `MatCheckBox`.

Answer (score 0):

A checkbox only can be true or false the "indeterminate state" is a new property (in MatCheckbox you use the property `[indeterminate]` in a normal check-box you can use a directive as in [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54075014/set-indeterminate-on-angular-checkbox/54077741#54077741)

So the "intermediate state is a property of the "mat-checkbox", not the formControl, so you need use a "template reference variable" and `@ViewChild`

Another option is that your formControl gets the values 0,1 and -1 and use some like

```
<mat-checkbox class="example-margin"
                  [checked]="control.value==1"
                  [indeterminate]="control.value==-1"
                  (change)="control.setValue($event.checked)">
      checked
</mat-checkbox>
```

Really I don't pretty sure what do you want to achieve

Comment: Unfortunately, as I added to my original post, `@ViewChild` doesn't work from the service where I need it. I had already tried setting `value` manually, but it seems `value` on the `AbstractControl` only cares about the `checked` status; `value` on the checkbox is ignored. Also, I already had a way to *control* the `indeterminate` status; there is lots of info around the web saying how to set it, but finding how to read it has proven tricky.

I did figure out a way to get what I needed by keeping track of the value myself in a variable in the service that needs it, as I will post later.